# ls command in for loop

Tags: command-line, bash

```
path=/2020/01-Jan/00:00/sb/*.txt
```

Under 01-Jan, I have many folders like

```
00:00 
01:00 
02:00 
03:00 
.. 
23:00
```

(each `xx:00` folder has `/sb/*.txt`). I want to get .txt file from 00:00 to 03:00 range. I tried

```
for ((i=$(ls /2020/01-Jan/00:00/sb/*.txt); i<=$(ls /2020/01-Jan/03:00/sb/*.txt); i++))
do
  ls *.txt
done
```

But it is giving

```
syntax error : arithmetic expression required
```

Can you please help to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure if I am correct but you can simply do

```
ls 2020/01-Jan/{00..03}:00/sb/*.txt
```

to get your desired output.

Comment: think ```ls 2020/01-Jan/0[0-3]:00/sb/*.txt``` is better.

Comment: @bac0n yours is a solution that would work well only for `00:00` to `09:00` But since there are folders in the range `00:00` to `23:00` mine is a suitable and easy to follow approach.

Comment: I was thinking ```{}``` will unconditional expand path even if the path doesnt exist.

Comment: yes it works.Could you please help me if the range is assigned to a variable like a=00 and b=03. when i give 2020/01-Jan/{$a..$b}:00/sb/*.txt,the output is like 2020/01-Jan/{00..03}:00/sb/*.txt am i missing any escape declaration here

Comment: you need to use eval `a=00 b=03; eval "ls 2020/01-Jan/{$a..$b}:00/sb/"`

Comment: its works gr8 help.and one more humble request.how to find between range like from 01-Jan 00:00 to 03-Mar 00:00.I believe we have to use for loop.i give something like this ((i=eval "ls 2020/01-Jan/{$a..$b}:00/sb/" i<=eval "ls 2020/02-Feb/{$a..$b}:00/sb/"; i++)).can you please help on this

Comment: Please help me if i want to list txt files between 01-Jan 00:00 to 03-Mar 00:00.

Comment: to or and 03-mar?

Comment: Let me explain you in detail. I have 2 log folders.each has 2019->01-Janto 12-Dec->under each month having (01 to 31 folders)->under each day01having(00:00 to 23:00)-> sb->*.txt same in 2020->etc. Now i want to get the txt file between for example,2019/12-Dec/01/00:00 to 2020/03-Mar/31/01:00.could you please help on this?

Comment: that range doesnt make sense

Comment: :) 2020->(01-Jan to 12-Dec)->(01-31)->(00:00->23:00)->sb->*.txt For example                   (2020/01-Jan/01/00:00) to (2020/02-Feb/01/23)

Comment: path1=/01/00:00/files/*.txt /01/01:00/files/*.txt 01/02:00/files/*.txt
path2=/02/00:00/files/*.txt .. /02/01:00/files/*.txt.. 02/02:00/files/*.txt which means
in folder 01->i have 3 files like 00:00 01:00 02:00
folder 02->i have 3 files like 00:00 01:00 02:00
if i want to get *.txt files from 01/00:00 to 02/01:00.
can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Matching HH:MM format using extglob:

```
$ shopt -s extglob failglob; \
  ls 2020/01-Jan/?([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/*/sb/*.txt
```

<sup>This will be limited to [ARG_MAX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) (bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long).</sup>

Using extglob with a for loop:

```
$ shopt -s extglob nullglob; \
  for i in 2020/01-Jan/?([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/*/sb/*.txt; do echo "$i"; done
```

List directories between two dates with day, hour or minute precision:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Let's create some directories.
# $ for i in 2020/01-Jan/{00..03}\:{00..59}/{0..30}/sb \
#   2020/{02..03}-Jan/00:00/0/sb ; do mkdir -p $i; touch $i/$RANDOM.txt; done

shopt -s extglob nullglob

func(){
    local -n ref=$1
    local b
    local c
    local d=$(( $(date -d "$4" +%s) - $(date +%s) ))
    local e=$((($(date -d "$3" +%s) - \
                $(date -d "$2" +%s)) / $d))
    for ((b=0; b<=$e; b++)); do
        ref+=($(date -d "$2 +$b $4" +"$5"))
    done
}

list=()

# Between two dates divided in days.
func list "01-Jan 2020" "2-Jan 2020" day "%Y/%d-%b/00:00/0/sb/*.txt"

# Between two dates divided in hours.
func list "00:00 01-Jan 2020" "02:00 01-Jan 2020" hour "%Y/%d-%b/%H:00/0/sb/*.txt"

# divided in minutes with exglob match.
func list "02:00 01-Jan 2020" "02:02 01-Jan 2020" minutes "%Y/%d-%b/%H:%M/?([0-9]|1[0-9]|20)/sb/*.txt"

# Lets show it.
for i in "${list[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

<sup>Remember that `date` is language dependent, using `date` cookies can produce unexpected results.</sup>

Comment: Thanks bac0n.Great.The command "ls 2020/01-Jan/0[0-3]:00/sb/*.txt" simply works.             I have one more requirement here.if the time is assigned to variable like a=00 b=03.How to declare the variable in the ls command.

Comment: I would do `match='0[0-3]:00'; ls 2020/01-Jan/$match/sb/*.txt`